# Accessing property of object inside object PHP Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, object

I have struggled with my Laravel project.
I have searched but still not find the solution.

My **data** object like:

```
{
  id: 1,
  patients: {
     id: 2,
     patient_registrant: {
        id: 3,
        name: "Registrant name"
     }
  }
}
```

I want to access the object of name property inside **patient_registrant**

If I try **$data->patients->id** the result is 2.

I've tried like `$data->patients->patient_registrant->name;` but the result is **property name is non-object**

Please give me some clue, or keywords for this case. Thanks guys

Comment: How do you obtain `$data` ?

Comment: What does `var_dump($data->patients->patient_registrant);` show?

Comment: I have `$date`  from the controller to consumed in my view.  the `$data` is the result of my query. If I try to show $data->id, $data->patients both looks fine

Comment: `var_dump($data->patients->patient_registrant);` is showing nothing. only empty object like this : `{}`

Answer (score 0):

Please try fetching like this:

```
$data  = [
'id'=> 1,
'patients'=> [
 'id'=> 2,
 'patient_registrant'=> [
    'id'=> 3,
    'name'=> "Registrant name",
   ]
 ]
];
var_dump(  $data['patients']['patient_registrant']['name']);
```